# Array output problem at Webscraping with DOMparser

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, domparser

I'm facing some output trouble at the second part of my codes.

```
function getSiteContent($url)
    {

        $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
            return file_get_contents($url);
        });

        $parser = new \DOMDocument();
        @$parser->loadHTML($html);
        return $parser;

    }

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$url = 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/osaka';
$parser = getSiteContent($url);

$allDivs =[];
$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'p-articlelist-content-right') {
        $allLinks = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach ($allLinks as $a) {
            $getlinks[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
        }
    }
}

var_dump($getlinks);
```

At this var_dump I can see links that I scraped. No problem 'till here. And one more time. I want to go into those links. That's why I wrote the codes right below.

```
getSiteContent($getlinks);
$link = [];
$siteler = [];
foreach ($siteler as $site) {
    if($site == 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp'){
    $site = $getlinks->getElementsByTagName('div');
        foreach ($site as $links) {
            if($links->getAttribute('class') == 'pc_hnavi'){
                $linker = $links->getElementsByTagName('a');
                foreach ($linker as $a) {
                    $link = $a->getAttribute('href');
                } 
            }
        }
    } 
}

var_dump($link);
```

When I var_dump it. It says Array 0
I didn't understand why it doesn't go in those links with foreach
My codes are wrong? What am I missing here? Any idea for this?
Thank you helping me out.

Comment: You're passing an array to `getSiteContent()` and not capturing the return value anyway. Then you're trying to `$getlinks->getElementsByTagName()` which really won't work.

Comment: The variable `$siteler` is empty when you do `foreach ($siteler as $site)` so that loop won't do anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments `$siteler` is empty when you try to loop through it, but there are a couple more problems:

- First your code will only trigger once at most, when the link is exactly 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp' and I'm not sure that's what you want.
- You are calling `DOM` functions on an array.
- Only seem to care about links inside 'div' tags.
- You redefine the `$link` variable on each loop, so the final result will be just one link.

This is the fixed code:

```
$link = [];
foreach ($getlinks as $site) {
    // Any link in the domain, not just the homepage
    if(strpos($site, 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp') === 0) {
        $dom = getSiteContent($site);
        $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
        foreach ($divs as $div) {
            // Can have more than one class
            $attrs = explode(' ', $div->getAttribute('class'));
            if(in_array('pc_hnavi', $attrs)) {
                $linker = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
                foreach ($linker as $a) {
                    // Add to the array
                    $link[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
                } 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

However this doesn't check if the link already exists in the array and has the potential to process the same links over and over. I'd strongly suggest to use an existing crawler.

From the comments, turns out that `pc_hnavi` is an `id` and not a class and you are interested in the first link only. You can access that element directly without iterating the elements:

```
foreach ($getlinks as $site) {
  // Any link in the domain, not just the homepage
  if(strpos($site, 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp') === 0) {
    $dom = getSiteContent($site);
    $div = $dom->getElementById('pc_hnavi');
    if ($div != null) {
      $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
      if ($links->length > 0) {
        $a = $links->item(0); 
        $link[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry mate, thanks for afford but still could't get the link. Actually. $getlinks has a couple links and I want to go those link which is equal to https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp this.

Comment: no mate, it exits here: `https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/branz/tennoji/`

Comment: Okay I get the links now. Thank you. Sorry for misleading mate

Comment: By the way,  how can I go to the just first links of the that ID?

Comment: mate, could you edit your answer? becouse I am getting a syntax error. I think I couldn't edit righty. Thank you. Linker is going undefined variable

Comment: thanks for the afford mate. but I am getting this error. when I copy the last codes of yours `Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null` by the way sorry for the other post already deleted it.

Comment: you saving my life mate, I used your last edit but facing this now: `Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::count()` really sorry for burden

Comment: Using 7.1 I am getting now, but just one href. Actually I want to get first of all href's. I think I need new question for that.

Comment: yep! thank you so much mate! In that foreach I want to go also another website of another link I just use this right? `elseif (strpos($site, 'kintetsu-re.co.jp') === 0)`

Comment: @KubilayTurgut yes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is here:

```
...
$siteler = []; // $siteler is set to an empty array ...
foreach ($siteler as $site) { // then you loop through the empty array which does nothing ...
    ...
}
...
```

Fixing that should get you started.